# What is the notation for taking negative imaginary values for roots of negative numbers?

Tags: notation, analyticity

I have a formula which is analytic in its argument $x$.  In it, there is a square root of a variable as in $\sqrt{x}$.  Although meaningful results are obtained when positive roots are taken for for positive values of $x$, if I insert negative values of $x$, the meaningful result obtains from the *negative* imaginary root.

Is there a standardized notation to notate this kind of square root?

$$
\sqrt{x}\enspace\text{"="}\,
\begin{cases}
|x|^{1/2},&x\geq0\\
-i\,|x|^{1/2},&x<0
\end{cases}
$$

So that I may insert it into my formula without having to refer to the ugly case written above?

---

Somebody suggested that I can use
$$
\sqrt{x-i\epsilon^+}
$$
in the formula, with the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ from positive values either implied or written explicitly.  Would there be any ambiguities associated with this kind of notation?

Comment: I suppose this is the conjugate of the usual square root.

Comment: But if I put a $\sqrt{x}^*$ in my formula, it will look non-analytic.

Comment: If any of the answers below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @gebruiker Your answer is helpful (so +1).  The answer that I found most useful was not provided by a math.se member, but by a colleague: to use $\sqrt(x-i\varepsilon^+)$.  I answered my own question with the intent of accepting it, but it was deleted by math.se members and was merged into my original question.  So I am unable to accept.

Comment: I'm happy to know that you found the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say that in general the function $\sqrt{x}$ is used to denote the *principal square root* of a number $x$. For poxitive $x$ it is generally understood that this is the positive one of the two square roots (i.e. $\sqrt9=3$ and not $-3$ by convention.) In the complex case we can't speak of positive or negative. However we do have someting like a principal value of a complex number $z$. It is determined by the princeple value of its *argument*: $\theta$. If we write $z=re^{\theta i}$ with $\theta=\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ we can usually define the principle value of $\sqrt z$ as:

> $$\large\sqrt z=re^{\frac{\theta}{2}i}$$

This way you automatically and unambiguously talk about one particular square root.

**N.B** It all comes down to conventions. Make shure the reader knows what your conventions are.

Comment: @QuantumDot In your case this means you can probably just write $-\sqrt x$...

Comment: The square root function defined using the principal branch of the argument function has a branch cut along the negative real axis, and so is not defined at negative real numbers as is asked for in the question.

Comment: @San I am assuming $-\pi<\operatorname{Arg}(z)\leq\pi$. If I'm not mistaking, this would give a definite answer right? It won't be analytic on the negative real axis, but it will be unambiguously defined. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @San Also it will give $\sqrt{-9}=3i$ as is common practice...

Comment: It will certainly be unambiguously defined, but the OP specifies that the function he/she has in mind should be analytic. Your answer is not wrong, it just doesn't seem to answer the question the OP asks.

Comment: @San I believe the OP has stated that the root is part of his function and requires $-\sqrt{x}, \text{for }x<0$. It should be $-\sqrt{x}$ and not $\sqrt{x}$ because of what I stated in my answer. I certainly agree with you that the function isn't analytic this way. Howerver the OP says that his bigger function will be analytic this way so I'll take his word on that. This is just the conventional notation that he "should" use...

Comment: sounds fair enough.